# How to fix this incompatibility between nonfloat and glossaries packages?

Tags: glossaries

In the code below, when I use `XeLaTeX`, the caption isn't printed in the output. How can I solve the problem?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{nonfloat}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A Test}
\begin{center}
\tabcaption{A Caption}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
a & b
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh my, `nonfloat` is from 1999. I suggest to use `\captionof{table}{...}` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The incompatibility is with the `supertabular` package; just load `glossaries` with the `nosuper` option.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[nosuper]{glossaries}
\usepackage{nonfloat}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Test}

\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\tabcaption{A Caption}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
a & b
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Not the real solution, but a work-around: Use `\captionof{table}{foo}` instead of `\tabcaption{foo}` (this requires the `caption` package, however)

`nonfloat` hasn't been updated since 1999. The details why this fails has in the meantime found out by `egreg`, but omitting `supertab` might not work in any case.

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{nonfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A Test}
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{A Caption}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
a & b
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's clear now why, see egreg answer.